# How to export a variable from JS file to Sol file?

Tags: javascript, solidity

I can't find any answer in google. Only import/export between 2 JS files and 2 Sol files. But if I have a `token1 = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"` in JS file how can a send it's value to sol file and then compile this sol file? If it's possible.

Comment: Hi, Viktor. I think you have to explain a little more what you are trying to do. And, be aware, sharing token and password is really dangerous!

Comment: Hi. Sorry. I didn't know that I can add this variables in deploy() and import them in constructor. So the problem doesn't exist))